# The phase of voltage across a resistor in a RC circuit when the frequency of input tends to zero

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Across the resistor we have

$$
\begin{array}{c}
V_{R}=\frac{V_{i n}}{\left(R+X_{C}\right)} \cdot R \\
V_{R}=\frac{V_{i n} \cdot R}{R+\frac{1}{j \omega C}} \\
V_{R}=\frac{V_{m} R j \omega C}{j R \omega C+1}
\end{array}
$$
Which gives
$$\mathrm{V}_{R}=\frac{\omega R C V_{i n}}{\left(1+R^{2} \omega^{2} C^{2}\right)}(\omega R C+j)
$$ Which then gives us the phase of voltage across the resistor. Similarly we can do for the capacitor and we have respectively ( assuming phase of input voltage to be zero)  :
$$
\phi_{R}=\tan \left(\frac{1}{\omega R C}\right)
$$ and
$$
\phi_{c}=\tan ^{-1}(-\omega R C)
$$
And
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\omega \rightarrow 0 \\
\phi_{c} \rightarrow 0 \\
\phi_{R} \rightarrow \pi/{2}
\end{array}
$$ so we see that the voltage across the capacitor is in phase with the input voltage. However we have
$$
v_{R}=v_{i}-v_{c}
$$ and from this equation we see that if the capacitor voltage is in phase with the input voltage, then the voltage across the resistor is in phase with the input voltage. But this contradicts the above equation which says that $$
\phi_{R} \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Where am i mistaken. Please help.

Comment: Show how you derive the equation for \$\phi _R\$

Comment: I think that'll make the post unnecessarily long. The same result is given exactly in this post:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit

Comment: @chu is on to something. look closely.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll write the whole procedure. Thank you

Comment: The expression for phase angle in the wiki article is wrong; should be \$ \phi = 90 -atan (\omega RC)\$

Comment: @Chu is it clear now or do i need to edit it?

Comment: You should leave the question in it's original form. If you give the corrected version then it's no longer a question, and none of the comments make sense! The most recent analysis you've uploaded is completely wrong, btw.

Comment: @Chu, i only intended to write the derivation of my results as you had asked in the first comment. I don't see where i have altered the form of the question. Also could you tell me where the analysis is wrong? The equations I've written are in the phasor form, it'll be helpful if you could point where I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: My expression, above, should have been \$\phi_R=0-arctan(\omega RC)\$

Comment: @Chu, could you please point where my analysis is wrong? It'll be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

> then the voltage across the resistor is in phase with the input voltage

But this is not correct. Simply because the right-hand-side vi-vc is real does not imply that the left-hand-side vr is real if vi-vc is zero.

For w approaching 0 the capacitor voltage is in phase with the input voltage, and VR approaches 0 with angle approaching +90deg. This is calculated from the voltage divider equation.

Below are simplified plots for Z=-j/w (C=1,R=1), and H(w) for the resistor.

[image]

Comment: Thank you it cleared it up dear. One more humble request, chu said$$\phi_R=0-arctan(\omega RC)$$ ,this is incorrect then.